# Fullcalendar resources eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am implementing a 'fullcalendar'(6.1.11) component inside my VueJs(2.7/3) application.
So far I have got my TimeGridView, my events and resources.
I was wondering if it is possible to add actions to resources, or better, if I click on the title of the column header(ordered by resource.name) some action will take place, for example: a dropDown menu appears.
Is there a simple way to implement this within fullcalendar options like calendarOptions, or I have to adapt any Jquery strategies.
Any help is welcome.

```
data() {
  return {
    calendarOptions: {
      events: myEvents,
      resources: myResources,
      resourcesLabelsEvents: ??

    }
  }
```

Best Regards,
LuFer

I tried documentation but nothing helped...

UPDATE: I have been digging the callback resourceLabelDidMount and so far:

```
initialView: "resourceTimeGridDay",
resources: [this.$store.getters["calendar/coworkers"]],
resourceLabelDidMount: function(arg) {
    if(arg.resource.id) {
        const resourceTitle = arg.el.querySelector('.fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner');

        resourceTitle.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const dropdownMenu = document.createElement('div');
            dropdownMenu.className = 'dropdown-menu';
            dropdownMenu.innerHTML = `
                  <a href="#">option 1</a>
                  <a href="#">option 2</a>
                  <a href="#">option 3</a>
            `;
            dropdownMenu.style.position = 'absolute';
            dropdownMenu.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
            dropdownMenu.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
            document.body.appendChild(dropdownMenu);
            document.addEventListener('click', closeDropdownMenu);
        });

        function closeDropdownMenu(event) {
            const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

            if (dropdownMenu && !dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {
                dropdownMenu.remove();
                document.removeEventListener('click', closeDropdownMenu);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: The [resource render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-render-hooks) allow you to customise the HTML of the resource, which could include adding event handlers to elements and so on.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your suggestion. I've reviewed the documentation, but unfortunately, it appears to be lacking. Have you had any experience implementing something like this before? If so, would you mind providing a basic example? I would greatly appreciate having a starting point.

Comment: In which way is it lacking? Have you tried anything? Where did you get stuck, specifically?

Comment: I'd expect you probably want to use the `resourceLabelDidMount` callback, as that will give you direct access to the underlying HTML element object, and then you can manipulate it in any way you like using standard JS DOM functionality - e.g. to add elements, set event listeners, and so on.

Comment: @ADyson please check post update. I have added the callback like you suggested. I would need to attach a Listener to event 'click' and create a dropdown menu...but somehow it only catches the closeDropDown action. any other suggestion?

Comment: It seems to be handling the event and creating the dropdown ok, but for some reason that I don't understand, it's not appending it to the DOM - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEZyVje